# Too little contrast between page and footer on Meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta, footer

I noticed today that the footer background color on Meta is set to a really, really light grey, `#fafafb`, rather than the same dark grey as the main site:

[image: light footer]

On my monitor, I can't even differentiate between this color and the white of the rest of the page, and so it looks like the page just flows into the footer without a separation. The lack of contrast makes it look like there are a bunch of random words floating on the bottom of the page, and it is not clear that it is a footer. I feel like there was a similar problem when the new top-bar was introduced.

Can the contrast please be increased, or can a darker border at least be added?

Comment: Stack Exchange no longer believes in contrast, as you can see with the new top bar. If it ain't white, it ain't right.

Comment: @animuson I didn't originally even realize that the meta footer color was different than the main site color. That makes this even more bothersome. Now I ask, why the lack of consistency? The dark grey has a much better contrast, so why not just always use the dark grey?

Comment: @CodyGray - it isn't white. Hasn't been for a while.

Comment: @Oded So then I guess it ain't right :) And it is close enough to white to be considered white. I still think the top-bar is too light, but that is a conversation for a different post.

Comment: Yeah, I was there for the fight over that. Indeed, it used to be worse, but it is a bit silly to pretend that a 98% lightness is much of an improvement over a 100% lightness, contrast-wise.

Comment: The whole site seems to be converting to Five shades of white, ranging from `#FFFFFF` to `#FBFBFB`. Not funny, IMHO. The sticky header eats a lot of space when someone like me prefers to read zoomed pages. The footer contains nothing, I'm simply not gonna read. I'm thinking about a plugin allowing to restyle and/or remove those parts.

Comment: @maaartinus [This userscript](https://github.com/tziporaziegler/SETopBar/blob/master/se-top-bar.user.js) makes the top-bar background color slightly darker, and makes the entire bar shorter. Doesn't address all your complaints, yet you still might find it to be an improvement.

Comment: Does anyone even use the footer enough to care? Despite the lightness of the gray, I really don't have any trouble finding any of the things I might be looking for if I needed to use the footer.

Comment: @jpmc26 The people at Stack Overflow obviously cared enough to spend time redesigning it. Once it is being redesigned, it may as well be redesigned correctly.

Comment: @TotZam Spending a bunch of time on something that doesn't matter is what you call a "sunk cost." ;) No sense spending more if it doesn't matter.

Comment: I'm obviously a part of a tested group that has it in original color. What should I do? Vote for this post to keep it in dark gray? I don't like the light one. I would like to see the top bar in the same dark gray as well.

Comment: @Victoria This post is not against the dark grey. I actually like the dark grey used on the main site best. Meta SO has it set to light grey, and I'm asking it could be darkened, if not changed to the dark grey. This post is only concerning the Meta site. You are probably looking at the main site if you are seeing dark grey.

Comment: Aha, it's on meta. Sorry. I realized that you like dark gray. I was just confused what to do. If I should vote up even if I cannot reproduce assuming I'm part of another A/B test for the main site. Now I can see. And don't want to see :)

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) – I think new footer uses (used) exactly the same background color as the old one on meta. As a side note: it's been like that for ~1.5 year. But I understand that this contrast wasn't enough for some people. That being said I made footer background slightly darker and it should already be on prod.

Comment: I guess I just noticed it now that there was a blog post regarding the footer. I still think it can use more contrast, but I guess this is better. Is there a specific reason why you aren't just consistently using the dark grey used on the main site?